# Two predictors in a generalized additive models?

Tags: r

When I fit a generalized additive model with two predictors, I can use the following two commands,

```
lm4 = gam(X3 ~ s(X1) + s(X2),data=pairmin2)
lm41 = gam(X3 ~ s(X1,X2), data=pairmin2)
```

How are these two commands different?

The second question is about prediction with this GAM.
First, I defined 'y12' where the fitted model should be evaluated.

```
x1 = x2 = seq(0.01,0.99,0.01) 
y12 = data.frame(expand.grid(x1,x2))
pred4 = predict(lm4,y12)
pred41 = predict(lm41,y12)
```

The first command 'pred4' works well, but the second 'pred41' gives the following error.

```
Error in storage.mode(df) <- "double" : object 'X2' not found
```

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you want to ask just one question at a time. Your first question about what is the difference between the two calls seems like a methodological one and may be better suited for [stats.se]. Also, it's much easier to help if you supply a filly reproducible example (as I will have to do in order to answer your second question).

As far as why your predict calls fails, you should be passing in a data.frame that has the same variable names as the model used to fit the data to the `newdata=` parameter. When you use `expand.grid`, your variables are re-named. Here's a reproducible example of creating two different fits

```
set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)

lm4<-gam(y~s(x1)+s(x2),data=dat)
lm41<-gam(y~s(x1, x2),data=dat)
```

now we can predict these models using

```
x1 = x2 = seq(0.01,0.99,0.01) 
y12 = data.frame(expand.grid(x1=x1,x2=x2))  #note the naming here

pred4 = predict(lm4,y12)
pred41 = predict(lm41,y12)
```

and we do get different results

```
head(pred4)
#        1        2        3        4        5        6 
# 2.571626 2.590161 2.608700 2.627249 2.645825 2.66444

head(pred41)
#        1        2        3        4        5        6 
# 4.392093 4.286727 4.172413 4.049871 3.920065 3.784201
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

```
lm4 = gam(X3 ~ s(X1) + s(X2),data=pairmin2)
lm41 = gam(X3 ~ s(X1,X2), data=pairmin2)
```

by combining the two covariates into one smooth separated by a comma in `lm41` you are telling it to model the two terms with an interaction.